# Odata breaking with unconventional association

Tags: odata, ef-core-2.2

I'm trying to make an unconventional join, like this:

```
builder.HasOne(x => x.MATERIAL_OBJ)
      .WithMany()
      .HasForeignKey(c => c.MATERIAL)
      .HasPrincipalKey(p => p.MATERIAL_CODE);
```

because the data from one of my tables comes from an external source, and I need to make a join with another table by a non-PK (VARCHAR) field.
My tables are as follow:

Transits table

```
+---------+----------+
| ID      | MATERIAL |
+---------+----------+
| 1       | ABC      |
| 2       | HIJ      |
+---------+----------+
```

Material table:

```
+---------------+---------------+
| MATERIAL_CODE | SUPPLIER_NAME |
+---------------+---------------+
| ABC           | SUP 1         |
| DEF           | SUP 2         |
+---------------+---------------+
```

The transits table always comes filled, and sometimes with materials we dont have avaliable. If we have the material, then the object comes filled correctly, the problem I'm facing is that whenever the material doesn't exist in the table, my odata simply doesn't work properly, breaking the return object, like so:

[image: The return from my odata]

Is there any way to odata to return null, instead of breaking the return?

EDIT: below is the return value:

```
{"@odata.context":"http://MYAPI/odata/$metadata#TRANSIT(Id,MATERIAL,MATERIAL_OBJ,MATERIAL_OBJ()","value":[{"Id":12567,"MATERIAL":"REDACTED"
```

Also, this seems to be something with odata, as the objects are filled in the API.

Comment: No images please. Post text whenever possible. Also, the json in the image doesn't make clear how the return object is broken. Maybe you should also post a correct return object. Replace private strings by something else, not empty space.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delayed response. Thanks for the tip on images. About the result, it is broken, because the return is just that, it doesnt close the object, it stops at line six.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that was a problem with EF Core because of the unconventional mapping I did. I decided to do a View instead and mapped that to EF.